# What is the best way to learn driving in the United States?

Tags: driving, driving-licenses

I am a student living in the United States. I wanted to learn driving and get the driving license. Since I don't have a car, what is the best way to learn driving after taking a few classes from a professional?

Comment: This seems to be a question for [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: @phoog Why? For starters, you don't even know whether OP is originally from the US.

Comment: This seems to be on-topic here to me, as it is about driving, which is a means of transportation routinely used for travel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about acquiring a life skill, not about travel.

Comment: @fkraiem OP's other questions indicate that they are Indian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, you have two options, which are not mutually exclusive.

If you have a friend who owns a car who is willing to allow you to use the car to practice driving, you can do that.  In most states, if not all, you will need a learner's permit, and you will need your friend or another licensed driver (often with a minimum age of 21 years) to supervise you.  Requirements for the supervising driver vary significantly from one state to the next.  Before you do this, check the rules in the state where you will be driving, and get your learner's permit.

The other option, of course, is to enroll in a professionally-taught driving course.  Driving schools are everywhere; you should not have trouble finding one.

Comment: +1. Probably worth mentioning that many driving schools will rent cars for the driving test, sometimes for additional practice time as well, once you've taken lessons from them. Teaching people to drive is their entire business, so they ought to be used to such questions. And they're already insured to let student drivers drive it. More expensive than practicing with a friend, but may be easier, and the professional instruction is usually geared to help you pass the test quickly and easily.